# Error Code: 0x80070035. The network path was not found

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, file-sharing

I've tried almost every single way I can find on the internet and none of them worked:

[image: Error Code: Network Path Not found.]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting TCP/IP?

1. Open Command Prompt and enter the following commands:

   - `netsh winsock reset`
   - `netsh int ip reset`
   - `ipconfig /release`
   - `ipconfig /renew`
2. After running these commands, restart your PC and check if the issue still persists.

If the issue still persists, you can try to configure IP address:

1. Open “Network and Sharing Center” and click “Change adapter settings”.
2. Right-click your Wi-Fi adapter and click “Properties”.
3. Select “Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)” and click “Properties”.
4. Click “Obtain an IP address automatically”.

Comment: Yet?! Suggesting "restart your PC" is no solution!

Comment: Nothing useful here